# LinearLayout - Lint error when using style file (still working, though)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-lint

Problem: I get a lint error and warning on styles that are working, when defining the orientation of a LinearLayout in a styles file, but not when defining the orientation directly on the element. Even though the property is picked up from the styles file.

I have a base style for all my activities, containing the following:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="StandardActivity">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In my layout, if I add this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/StandardActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

    </LinearLayout>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

On `layout_width` I get a lint warning:

```
Use a 'layout_width' of '0dp' instead of 'fill_parent' for better performance
```

And on `layout_height` I get a lint error:

```
Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for 'layout_width'
```

Everything is working as expecting and the layout takes the `orientation` attribute set in `StandardActivity`. However, the error and warning are *only* valid when the orientation is set to `horizontal`. How can I get the lint in Android studio to understand that the orientation is set in the style-file?

If a explicitly add the orientation directly to the LinearLayout, the linting error and warning disappears.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an issue, the IDE is probably behind. The it's assumption made is that the `layout_orientation` is `horizontal`, in which case those errors would be correct. But as you've made the `layout_orientation=vertical` in the `style` everything is fine. 
If you were to transfer those variables directly into the layout those errors should go away. PS `fill_parent` is deprecated, use `match_parent`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

    </LinearLayout>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```